How to change the text of a facet label in ggplot
I'd like to change the appearance of my facet labels so that they are labelled "Tensile Strength" and "Strain at break", instead of appearing with a "." in between and lowercase. I'm not sure if I need to modify the column names in my data or if there is a better way to do it. New to using R, any help would be appreciated!
##changing titles - didn't appear to do anything

tensile.strength.labs <- c("Tensile Strength")
names(tensile.strength.labs) <- c("Tensile Strength")

##Tried to modify data - didn't appear to do anything

df <- data

df$tensile.strength <- factor(df$tensile.strength,
labels = c("Tensile Strength"))

df$strain.at.break <- factor(df$strain.at.break,
labels = c("Strain at break"))

a <- ggplot(data=data,aes(x=sample,y=c(tensile.strength,strain.at.break)))+
geom_boxplot()+
theme_bw()

data$K.bar <-as.factor(data$K.bar)

ggboxplot(data,x="sample",y=c("tensile.strength","strain.at.break"),
fill="K.bar",combine=TRUE,
xlab = "Sample",
ylab = "", yaxt = "n")

##removes y axis



If you were able to share a reproducible sample of your data that would help. There are a few ways to work this out but they would depend on the shape of your data.

Just use a custom labeller. There’s no need to modify the input data. Details in the online doc.

You could modify this in the data or in the plot. Below is an example in the plot where you could use str_to_title or str_to_sentence. str_replace_all swaps the dots for spaces. The dots are "escaped" so they are interpreted literally (rather than as regex).
(If they are column headings in your data, then I would do it in the plot to avoid non-syntactic variable names.)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = 1:2, y = 2:3, facet = c("tensile.strength", "strain.at.break"))

df |> ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  facet_wrap(~ str_to_title(str_replace_all(facet, "\\.", " ")))


Created on 2024-04-23 with reprex v2.1.0

Inspired by this approach, let's use mtcars dataset for demo purpose.
This is the base plot, before we change the facet labels:
original <- ggboxplot(mtcars, x="cyl", y=c("mpg", "disp"), fill="vs", combine=TRUE, ylab="") + labs(x="Sample",fill="K bar")

Get all plot objects:
plot_objects <- ggplot_build(original)

Create new labels:
labels <- factor(c("Tensile Strength", "Strain at break"), levels=c("Tensile Strength", "Strain at break"))

Modify the objects:
plot_objects$layout$layout[[".y."]] <- labels

Generate new plot from modified objects:
plot(ggplot_gtable(plot_objects))

Result:


Your labelling method wasn't quite right. Try the following with this mock data as an example:
df <- tibble(x = 1:2, y = 2:3, 
         facet = c("tensile.strength", "strain.at.break"))

Convert the "facet" variable to a factor with the desired labels. The ordering is alphabetic by default.
df$facet <- factor(df$facet, labels=c("Strain at break", "Tensile Strength"))

Now the plot. R will use the labels for factor variables.
df |> ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  facet_wrap(~facet)


